# How to save to the Favourite and fetch the saved Favourites to show

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm coding a language dictionary running on Android 2.2. My scenario is that I want to add words to the Favourite list and then view the saved favourites. In fact, I want to save favourite words to a (text) file created on the sdcard, and when user click on "View Favourites", words from this file will be shown and can be chosen.

The problem is I have no idea how to code "saving and viewing" the Favourite list.

Here is my code:

```
btnAddFavourite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddFavourite);

btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // I want the code here!
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ContentView.this, R.string.messageWordAddedToFarvourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

    btnAddFavourite.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // Open the favourite Activity, which in turn will fetch the saved favourites, to show them.
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavViewFavourite.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

I wonder whether there is a solution to this problem and how I can code to address this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, a solution to what problem ? Even if a database would have been a better solution for that, text file should work too. what's wrong ?